# partition list into groups of size-N

Tags: list, kotlin, functional-programming, partition

what's the idiomatic way to take a list and group it into tuples of size n?

eg: group into 3's with triple

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4)
val partitioned = list.groupsOf(3)

// partitioned[0] = List<Int> 1, 2, 3
// partitioned[1] = List<Int> 4
```

but preferably something like this

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4)
val newList = mutableListOf()

list.forGroupsOf(3) { triple: Triple<Int?> ->
    newList.add( triple )
}

// partitioned[0] = Triple<Int?> 1, 2, 3
// partitioned[1] = Triple<Int?> 4, null, null
```

NOTE: `List.groupsOf` and `List.forGroupsOf` I made up for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin provides a function called [`chunked(n)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) which produces a list of lists with n elements each:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val tuples = list.chunked(2).map { Tuple(it[0], it[1]) }
```

Or alternatively:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val tuples = list.chunked(2) { Tuple(it[0], it[1]) }
```

Keep in mind that this produces lists with **max** n elements.